# How to correctly use plot_model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, conv-neural-network

I can't plot the following model in Google Colab

```
def build_model(tasks):
    img_input = Input(shape=(23, 23, 1), name="image")
    coords_input = Input(shape=(4), name="coords") # first two cartesian then spectral
    x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=7, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='GlorotUniform',bias_initializer='GlorotUniform')(img_input)
    x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0, 1), (0, 1)))(x) # padding to mimic caffe behaviour
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2))(x)
    
    #...
    #...
    #some more layers
    #...
    #...
   
    x = Dense(units=512)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1,scale=False)(x)
    x = ReLU()(x)
    x = Dropout(rate=0.5)(x)
    outputs=[]
    for i in range(1,tasks+1):
        if(tasks==5):
            temp = Dense(units=2)(x)
            outputs.append(Softmax(name=output_names[i])(temp))
        else:
            outputs.append(Dense(units=2)(x))
    return Model(inputs=[img_input, coords_input], outputs=outputs)
```

`model.summary()` works but when I plot the model using `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model,to_file="model.png")`, it is giving the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 3 tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
> 4     model,
> ----> 5     to_file="model.png"
> 6 )
>
> 1 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/vis_utils.py
> in plot_model(model, to_file, show_shapes, show_layer_names, rankdir,
> expand_nested, dpi)
> 281                      rankdir=rankdir,
> 282                      expand_nested=expand_nested,
> --> 283                      dpi=dpi)
> 284   if dot is None:
> 285     return
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/vis_utils.py
> in model_to_dot(model, show_shapes, show_layer_names, rankdir,
> expand_nested, dpi, subgraph)
> 141
> 142     # Append a wrapped layer's label to node's label, if it exists.
> --> 143     layer_name = layer.name
> 144     class_name = layer.**class**.**name**
> 145
>
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'
>
> ---

Could you please explain where I am wrong?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38988) this might be a tensorflow problem, depending on what version you have. Can you try out the mentioned solution there?

Comment: @N.Kiefer Thanks for the link. This actually solved the problem. I could easily generate the plot after going through the link.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.

Try checking

```
len(model.layers)

len(model._layers)
```

If `len(model._layers)` is 1 more (or maybe more than1) than `len(model.layers)`, print the `model._layers` and `model.layers` to the terminal:

```
print(model._layers)
print(model.layers)
```

I expect you will see a `DictWrapper` at the end of `model._layers` and not at the end of `model.layers`.  If this is the case, you can remove this `DictWrapper` from `model._layers` by

```
model._layers = model._layers[:-1].
```

You should now be able to use `plot_model(model)`.

Note, while this should allow you to use plot_model, I assume there are some potential side effects of just removing a layer TensorFlow inserted.  Thus, you might want to do something like (I didn't test the following):

```
orig_layers = model._layers
model._layers = model._layers[:-1]
plot_model(model)
model._layers = orig_layers
```

[TensorFlow issue AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name' #38988](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38988?force_isolation=true) discusses this problem and mentions the following solution of removing any layers which are type dict.  This solution seems a little problematic if for some reason you ever are supposed to have a layer that is a dict, but maybe this doesn't happen in practice.
Here is a solution from the link

```
model._layers = [layer for layer in model._layers if not isinstance(layer, dict)]
```